# jQuery: changing div id, serving different click functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div acted as a button for user to perform a task (for example, entering a competition) as shown below.

```
<div id="enter_competition_button" class="option_long hovertext" data-hovertext="Click to enter this competition">Enter This Competition</div>
```

Below shown is the jQuery Ajax for the insertion of new competitor after user clicks the above button.

```
$("#enter_competition_button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
            url:"/caseproject/competition/Controller/ajax/enter_competition.php",
        data:{username:username,competitionId:competitionID,classBelong:classBelong},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#enter_competition_button").text("Entering...");
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data==0){
                $("#enter_competition_button").text("Failed!");
            } else if(data==1){
                $("#enter_competition_button").text("Cancel Entry");
                $("#enter_competition_button").attr("id", "cancel_competition_button");
            } else {
                $("#enter_competition_button").text("Error!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Once the insertion is successful, it has successfully changed the div's id from "enter_competition_button" to "cancel_competition_button". And I have added the jQuery event handler for the div of id "cancel_competition_button" as shown below.

```
$("#cancel_competition_button").click(function(){
    alert("Canceled");
});
```

However, when I click on the same div (Cancel Entry), the jQuery still recognize it as "enter_competition_button" instead of "cancel_competition_button", which in turn performs a second insertion.

Any tips on resolving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't "recognise" it as `enter_competition_button`. What happens is this:

> Here, John, hold this. Your name is now Martha. Why are you still holding it?!? Your name is Martha now, I did *not* give that to you, I gave it to John, wtf?

You are fetching an element by its ID, then binding a `click` handler on the element (NOT the name!). Later you change its name, but it still has the same `click` handler.

I assume you bind the `cancel` click handler before the name change happens; in this case, you yell:

> Martha, hold that!

and, unsurprisingly, no-one steps up - there is no element called `cancel_competition_button`, so zero elements get their shiny new `click` handler.

---

What you want to do instead is, instead of binding the handlers to the elements, use jQuery's "live" events to bind to names. You do it by binding an event to a parent, with a selector to check against. Say that you have something like this:

```
<form id="button_holder">
    <div id="enter_competition_button" class="option_long hovertext" data-hovertext="Click to enter this competition">Enter This Competition</div>
</form>
```

Now you can do this:

> Yo, Mike! Whenever someone asks for John, find him and tell him to do this. And whenever someone asks for Martha, find *her* and tell her to do that.

or, in code:

```
$("#button_holder").
    on("click", "#enter_competition_button", function(){
        // ... your old click handler goes HERE
    }).
    on("click", "#cancel_competition_button", function(){
        alert("Canceled");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and realistic examples! You helped me understand more on how binding event handler works. Your code works wonderfully! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.option_long', function (e) {

    // Check for the clicked div id here first using `e.target.id`
    if (e.target.id === 'enter_competition_button') {

        // make the ajax call here   
        $.ajax({...});

    } else if (e.target.id === 'cancel_competition_button') {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
});
```

If possible, change the `document` here with a closest static parent ID or class, lets say a parent element with **ID** as `container` and the code will be modified as:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'div.option_long', function (e) {

    // Check for the clicked div id here first using `e.target.id`
    if (e.target.id === 'enter_competition_button') {

        // make the ajax call here   
        $.ajax({...});

    } else if (e.target.id === 'cancel_competition_button') {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
});
```

This will attach your event to any div within the `#container` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that no element with the id `cancel_competition_button` exists when you try to create the event handler, your jquery element selection is empty and the click handler can't be attached to nothing. Place the handler registration inside your success callback after the id change. When using this approach I would also add an unbind call for the click handler inside it to avoid multiply registrations.

Edit: Though this should work, @Amadan solution is more elegant, clean and, in my opinion, definitely the way you should go.